# Phonegap: On form submit open website in default browser

Tags: cordova

I am building a mobile web app for my existing web application. In the mobile app I have a login form which directs the user to the website as post method. The website should open in the default mobile browser and not in the app itself.

Right now if I use anchor tag, application is working, but not with form submit.

Can some one please help me in fixing this.

Comment: Accept the ans if it will works for u ..

Comment: can you pls show me the code

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few way to redirect and open a page in webview .

IF(match username and password )
{

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

}

Comment: Can't we just put a POST url in form action as it would be like twice hitting the db of the website for logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InAppBrowser to open a link in either the Cordova WebView or in the stock browser that comes on the device: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

In the login form logic you would use this inAppBrowser to send them to your website in the native browser, not in your app.

Comment: The login form logic is written on website side. In the mobile app I only have a form with action link to the website. With your method it works perfectly well when I have hyperlinks.

Comment: Hmmm so you have a mobile app, that directs them to your website, where they login, and then you want the website to redirect them to a new page that opens in a new browser window? Is that correct? Can you please edit your question with some code? Why can't you direct them to your website in a new browser window in the first place?...regardless you might be able to do this by injecting script into the new page, see the docs for InAppBrowser. I'll wait to hear back from you before trying this out.